# Does transfiguration truly change one thing to another?

Tags: harry-potter, transfiguration

I mean, if someone transforms a match into a needle, is the needle a real needle? Or is it something that looks and weighs like a needle but actually a match in disguise? If I burn this needle, would it burns like a match or it melts down into liquid iron?

More extremely, if I transform a stone into a PS4, can I play video games on it? Would a nuclear bomb transformed from a stone really explode? Or they are just false objects and would not work?

Comment: Sort of related to: [What are transfigured animals essentially made of?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63289/what-are-transfigured-animals-essentially-made-of)

Comment: @Shreedhar That question discussed whether or not Gamp's Law is violet if transfigured animals were real animals, but it doesn't discuss whether or not transfigured animals are real animals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hermione spends a lot of time knitting clothes in order to free the Hogwarts house-elves. During the summer she did it by hand, but once school started she did it with magic. From Chapter Thirteen of *Order of the Phoenix*:

> “They’re hats for house-elves,” she said briskly, now stuffing her books back into her bag. “I did them over the summer. I’m a really slow knitter without magic, but now I’m back at school I should be able to make lots more.”

Even with magic it took a significant amount of time, and the results were far from perfect. From Chapter Sixteen of *Order of the Phoenix*:

> However, Hermione, who was taking more subjects than either of them, had not only finished all her homework but was also finding time to knit more elf clothes. Harry had to admit that she was getting better; it was now almost always possible to distinguish between the hats and the socks.

Hermione was quite accomplished at transfiguration. Surely it would have been easier and less time-consuming to just transfigure any useless item into clothes, and the result would have been better as well! The fact that she did not do so, then, may indicate that she could not — either because  the clothes would revert back to their original form at some point, or because transfigured clothes simply wouldn’t have the legal status of clothes vis-a-vis house-elf freedom.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes. It Can.**

In its most basic layperson description, transfiguration can be used to change “something into something else” — to change “the form or appearance” of something:

> I do hope they start right away, there's so much to learn, I'm particularly interested in Transfiguration, you know, turning
> something into something else, of course, it's supposed to be very difficult —
> (Hermione, in chapter seven of *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*.)

Also, it has been described that it is easier to complete the spell if the nature of the transfigured object shares some characteristic with the original object, for example it may be easier to turn a stone statue of a PS4 into a PS4, or a stone statue of a nuclear bomb into a nuclear bomb.

However, there may be limitations, as the transfigured PS4 may not have a supply of power available. Your transfigured PS4 will be able to connect to a home wi-fi, but you’ll have to furnish that service yourself. Unless you also transfigured a blu-ray or game, you won’t have any content.

Comment: You might want to source your quote